# How do I popup in message in UWP?

Tags: popup, uwp

In my Windows 8.1 app I used MessageBox.Show() to popup a message. That is gone in UWP. How can I show a message?

Comment: Please review the stackoverflow help page on asking good questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yup, indeed something like that, the new method is to use the MessageDialog class. You have to create an object of that type. You can also add buttons. It's a bit more complex I think. But you can also use some shortcuts here. To just show a message, use this:

```
await new MessageDialog("Your message here", "Title of the message dialog").ShowAsync();
To show an simple Yes/No message, you can do it like this:

MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Yes or no?");
dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes", null));
dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No", null));
dialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
dialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;
var cmd = await dialog.ShowAsync();

if (cmd.Label == "Yes")
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I answered yesterday?

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at the [`Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog) class and try this:

```
// Create a MessageDialog
var dialog = new MessageDialog("This is my content", "Title");

// If you want to add custom buttons
dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Click me!", delegate (IUICommand command)
{
    // Your command action here
}));

// Show dialog and save result
var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to put MessageDialog codes into a function that has a keyword **async**  and returns type of  **Task** For example:

```
public async Task displayMessageAsync(String title, String content,String dialogType)
    {
        var messageDialog = new MessageDialog(content, title);
        if (dialogType == "notification")
        {
            //Do nothing here.Display normal notification MessageDialog
        }
        else
        {
            //Dipplay questions-Yes or No- MessageDialog
            messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes", null));
            messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No", null));
            messageDialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
        }

        messageDialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;
        var cmdResult = await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
        if (cmdResult.Label == "Yes")
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("My Dialog answer label is:: " + cmdResult.Label);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("My Dialog answer label is:: " + cmdResult.Label);
        }
    }
```